# How to login with auth0 in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0

How to login in a next js app with auth0? I followed the quickstart from the auth0 website and I am getting this error on the login page.

`<a href="/api/auth/login">Login</a>`

This is `pages/api/[...auth0].js`

```
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default handleAuth();
```

I am getting this error on the login page.

[image: error on login]

and I am getting this in my terminal

```
OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 404 Not Found
    at processResponse (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/freelancing/frontend-affilboost/node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/process_response.js:48:11)
    at Function.discover (/home/madhav/Documents/Web Development/freelancing/frontend-affilboost/node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js:252:22)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  error: 'expected 200 OK, got: 404 Not Found'
}
```

I am getting `Failed to load resource, the server responded with code 500` in my browsers' console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having this exact same issue and just searched for way too long to find this SO post. Sorry I'm adding no value, but I'm commenting so I can follow along and to let you know you are not alone.

Comment: that's wholesome

Answer (score 5):

The issue you're likely experiencing here is the following:

1. In your .env.local file `AUTH0_BASE_URL` should be set to `http://localhost:<port>`
2. In you .env.local file `AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL` should be set to your Auth0 domain: `https://xxx.us.auth0.com`
3. Make sure your callback URL inside of Auth0 is set to `http://localhost:<port>/api/auth/callback`

Replace `<port>` with whatever port you're using locally to serve the application.

Comment: This should be marked as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into the same thing, I know it's unlikely but don't forget to create a folder /auth inside your /api folder. I got the same error until I figured this out.

[image: auth0]

Answer (score 0):

Changing .env to .env.local was the fix for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).